# C++ unitTest with LinkTime substitution

Tags: c++, linker-errors, googletest

I'm reading "Test-Driven Development for Embedded C," by James W. Grenning.

I'd like to reproduce case with "Link-Time Substitution" using Visual Studio Community 2019 and gTest.

I have the following code:

production_code staticly linked library

*foo.cpp*

```
#include "foo.h"

int foo(int x) {
    return x + 1;
}
```

*foo.h*

```
#ifndef _foo_
#define _foo_

int foo(int x);

#endif //_foo_
```

In gtest project production_code library is included via reference
*test.cpp*

```
#include "gtest\gtest.h"
#include "gmock\gmock.h"

#include "..\prod\foo.h"

//fake implementation of production code foo
int foo(int x) {
    return x - 1;
}
TEST(TestCaseName, TestName) {
  auto x = foo(5);
  EXPECT_EQ(x, 4);
}
```

The linker gives me following error:

> 1>prod.lib(foo.obj) : error LNK2005: "int __cdecl foo(int)"
>   (?foo@@YAHH@Z) already defined in test.obj 1>C:\Example\prod_test.exe
>   : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

What have I missed here? Why doesn't this work?

If I add the command "/FORCE:MULTIPLE" to linker, then I get only warning, but I think that this is not the right approach to doing this.

Comment: The two different definitions of `foo` break the One Definition Rule (ODR): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition  So the technique proposed by the author is not supported by the Standard.  _"...One and only one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used (see below) is required to appear in the entire program (including any standard and user-defined libraries). ..."_

Comment: You cannot have two different definitions for a single function. If you want to use fake, **you have to exclude** real implementation from your build system when building UT. If you want to do it properly, use GMock mocks and dependency injection. And FORCE:MULTIPLE most likely just makes the linker do "choose implementation at random", which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This situation occurs because you defined `foo(int)` in 2 places: **foo.cpp** and **test.cpp** and you build your code with this files. If you need to run some test with a [stub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_stub) (fake function `foo(int)` in this case) you need to create 2 targets of build for:

1. building of your real application
2. building of a special application for unit testing (and than run it)

And when you build the application for unit testing, you link it with **test.cpp** (but not with **foo.cpp**). Also when you build your real application you link it with **foo.cpp** (but not with **test.cpp**).

**Note**: it's make sense to test real code and create a stub when this stub provides some additional functionality according to idea of a test (for example, you check your `sort()` function but you can use stub to generate data for `sort()` because the data are provided after some complex algorithm finished working and the computing takes a lot of time) or you don't want to use some resources (for example, you check your `sort()` function but you use a network connection to a server to get real data for `sort()`) or you need to provide some specific data for testing you algorithm (for example, to check a [corner case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_case) using specific data; or maybe you have found the `sort()` doesn't work with specific data). But again, it's make sense to test real code.

Comment: Thank you for reply,
If I understand correctly chapter in the book. Link time substitution deliberately violate one definition rule for test purposes!
In my solution I have separate test project from production project. Question is why Visual Studio linker does not replace definition from static library with implementation from test.cpp.

Comment: Maybe you added foo.cpp to separate test project. In this case you need to exclude foo.cpp from test project