# GCC4.1.2, GCC6.3.0, using "-fPIE -Wl,-pie"

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, ld, flags

Lets say I have an project which has an library in which I have one function which returns a single value, for example:

```
unsigned long cFun1()
{
    return 1000;
}
```

Then, I have an mock of the function in the main.cpp, with the same name, and the difference is that it returns some other result, for example:

```
unsigned long cFun1()
{
    return 45;
}
```

So, in the main, I am calling the simple function like this:

```
int main()
{
    long retVal = cFun1();

    return 0;
}
```

When I use linker as:

```
**link_command:**%{!fsyntax-only:%{!c:%{!M:%{!MM:%{!E:%{!S:\
    ld -shared -z defs --exclude-libs ALL %l %X %{o*} %{A} %{d} %{e*} %{m} %{N} %{n} %{r}\
    %{s} %{t} %{u*} %{x} %{z} %{Z} \
        %{L*} %(link_libgcc) %o \
    %{!nostdlib:%{!nodefaultlibs:%(link_ssp) %(link_gcc_c_sequence)}}
```

the function which is in the library is called, which is not something that I want. What I want to do is to call the mocked function which is in the main.cpp.
For that I am adding following flags: -fPIE -Wl,-pie

Compiling the application with this flags results in calling the mocked function which is in the main.cpp and which returns 45, but there are warnings while compiling:
**Variable retVal is declared but not used in the current configuration.**

So, the question is, is there any way to remove those warnings while using the "-fPIE -Wl,-pie" flags?
Or, is there any other way to use mocked functionality other than using those mentioned flags?

Comment: Undefined Behaviour, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58484081/c-unittest-with-linktime-substitution#comment103299674_58484081

Comment: The warning `Variable retVal is declared but not used in the current configuration` is easily fixed. Just use `retVal` somehow - or do `long retVal [[maybe_unused]] = cFun1();`

Comment: *variable is declared but not used in the current configuration* is not a GCC warning. I doubt there is a GCC version with C++/CLI support. Are you sure you are using GCC?

Comment: @Florian Weimer, I changed the Main() to the c++ syntax, and yes I am sure that I am using GCC 4.1.2 and GCC 6.3.0

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo this error is easy to fix, but this is just a simple example of the complex solution that gets this kind of errors using -fPIE -Wl,-pie and above mentioned linker flags, with booth GCC4.1.2 and GCC6.3.0. When following linker scripts are used: *link_command:%{!fsyntax-only:%{!c:%{!M:%{!MM:%{!E:%{!S:\
    ld -q -pie %l %X %{o*} %{A} %{d} %{e*} %{m} %{N} %{n} %{r}\
    %{s} %{t} %{u*} %{x} %{z} %{Z} \
    %{L*} %(link_libgcc) %o \
    %{!nostdlib:%{!nodefaultlibs:%(link_ssp) %(link_gcc_c_sequence)}} there are no errors produced

Comment: I don't see the connection between the `-fPIE -Wl,-pie` flags and the warning you used as an example since that warning would probably show up anyway (`-Wunused-variable`). Perhaps you could supply examples that only show up when using those flags?

Comment: Solution1. 
    *cc1: -falign-functions=4 -fno-jump-tables -fno-builtin -nostdinc %(cc1_cpu) 

    *link_command:%{!fsyntax-only:%{!c:%{!M:%{!MM:%{!E:%{!S:\
    ld -q -pie %l %X %{o*} %{A} %{d} %{e*} %{m} %{N} %{n} %{r}\
    %{s} %{t} %{u*} %{x} %{z} %{Z} \
    %{L*} %(link_libgcc) %o \
    %{!nostdlib:%{!nodefaultlibs:%(link_ssp) %(link_gcc_c_sequence)}}

Comment: Solution2.
    *cc1: -fvisibility=hidden -fno-builtin -ggdb -nostdinc %(cc1_cpu) 
    *link_command:%{!fsyntax-only:%{!c:%{!M:%{!MM:%{!E:%{!S:\
    ld -shared -z defs --exclude-libs ALL %l %X %{o*} %{A} %{d} %{e*} %{m} %{N} %{n} %{r}\
    %{s} %{t} %{u*} %{x} %{z} %{Z} \
    %{L*} %(link_libgcc) %o \
    %{!nostdlib:%{!nodefaultlibs:%(link_ssp) %(link_gcc_c_sequence)}}

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo The bigger question of this simple example is what makes the difference between solution1 and solution2. For solution1 the correct mocked function is called, for solution2 the function from the library is called. When the  additional flags "-fPIE -Wl,-pie" are added for solution2, the correct mocked function is called. This is the big issue that I am trying to solve, not to use those additional flags "-fPIE -Wl,-pie" for solution2, but calling the correct mocked function.